# How can i play the songs from iPod library in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ipod

I am very new to Audio playing in iPhone and ios development. I want to play songs from iPod library in my app. I have searched my level best in Google. But, i got the answer to use the iPod library but, i don't know to play a selected song from iPod library. This is my code used in app,

```
 MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;    
        picker.prompt = NSLocalizedString (@"Select songs to play", "Prompt in media item picker");
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];

       - (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection 
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
        NSLog(@"MediaItemCollection : %@", mediaItemCollection);

        MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Logging items from a generic query...");
        NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
        for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) 
        {
            NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            NSLog (@"%@", songTitle); // Here i retrieved all song titles.
        }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me to play the song from the ipod library?

Comment: Use the [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
    [player setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: Can we Use this song to add on a video?